# How can I filter a table by the selected rows in ag-Grid?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Since `select` is an attribute of the RowNode and not part of the data, how can I filter a table by those rows which have `select: true`?

I'm aware of the `gridApi.getSelectedNodes()` I've also tried `text` and `number` filter.

In a table of 10,000 items. The user needs the ability to only see the rows they've selected after scrolling and checking several rows.

Answer (score 1):

you could do `gridOptions.api.setRowData(gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows())`
getSelectedRows returns data of selected rows

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let selectedNodes = this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes();

let selectedData = selectedNodes.map(node => node.data);
```